# Place pictures in latex

Tags: image, latex

I try to make my resume in latex. Today I tried the whole day to place a picture beside my name and address, but I don't get it working.

This is the latex code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\huge}
{\thesection}
{0em}
{\filcenter}[\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\Large \bfseries}
{\hspace{-5mm}}
{0em}
{}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0em}{0em}{4em}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
\begin{center}
{\huge \bfseries 
\theauthor\\}
\vspace{0.25em}
Anystreet 1
\\
0000 Any
\\
+(00) 00 000 00 00 $\vert$ hans.muster@gmail.com

\end{center}
}
\begin{document}




\author{hans muster}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.15, right]{muster.jpg}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one purpose of floating environments like `figure` is that latex will select a good place for it. If you need something at a specific position, don't use a float.

Instead you could for example use minipages to include the image in your title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\huge}
{\thesection}
{0em}
{\filcenter}[\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\Large \bfseries}
{\hspace{-5mm}}
{0em}
{}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0em}{0em}{4em}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
{\huge \bfseries 
\theauthor\\}
\vspace{0.25em}
Anystreet 1
\\
0000 Any
\\
+(00) 00 000 00 00 $\vert$ hans.muster@gmail.com
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
}
\begin{document}




\author{hans muster}
\maketitle




\end{document}
```